# my p : dialog doesn´t work

Tags: primefaces

I´m using JSF2.0 and primefaces 3.4 in my web project
simply.... when I copy the code for p:dialog from show-case of 
primefaces to my project, it doesn't work, the dialog window doesn't appear
(the first dialog I put is the real one I want in my page... but actually the problem is...)
It seems like something in my project is not working in the right way... I´m just copying the code from prime-faces show-case to my page, but in my page the commandButtons to show the p:dialogs don´t work, the p:dialog is not showed. This is the web page I tested and not work for me:

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <ui:composition template="../template/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="main">
    <h:form id="form">

       <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5">

          <p:commandButton id="basic" value="Basic" onclick="dlg1.show();" type="button" />

          <p:commandButton id="modalDialogButton" value="Modal" onclick="dlg2.show();" type="button"/>

          <p:commandButton id="effectsDialogButton" value="Effects" onclick="dlg3.show();" type="button" />

       </h:panelGrid>

       <p:dialog id="basicDialog" header="Basic Dialog" widgetVar="dlg1">

          <h:outputText value="Resistance to PrimeFaces is futile!" />

       </p:dialog>

       <p:dialog id="modalDialog" header="Modal Dialog" widgetVar="dlg2" modal="true" height="100">

          <h:outputText value="This is a Modal Dialog." />

       </p:dialog>

       <p:dialog header="Effects" widgetVar="dlg3" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="bounce" height="100">

          <h:outputText value="This dialog has nice effects." />

       </p:dialog>

     </h:form>

  </ui:define>
  </ui:composition>
</html>`

Comment: Please include *what* isn't working. Its unclear what your problem is at the moment.

Comment: the problem is that the dialog window doesn't show

Answer (score 1):

Where's your code showing the dialog? Something similar to

```
<p:commandButton id="button" value="Open Dialog" oncomplete="PF('dialog').show();"/>
```

Comment: I already test PF('dlg3').show() too...and It not work for me... I really can´t understand what happen with my project...